# Debugging Credit Card errors in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Looking at the log I get this :

```
Processing CheckoutsController#update (for 69.230.191.209 at 2011-04-26 15:08:53) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"step"=>"payment", "order_id"=>"R107122666", "action"=>"update", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"ovZo+SsiHiGsmgtwkdzr0tRtfylQwGOUCeV9zEJU=", "controller"=>"checkouts", "checkout"=>{"creditcard_attributes"=>{"number"=>"[FILTERED]", "month"=>"8", "id"=>"63", "year"=>"2013", "last_name"=>"", "verification_value"=>"[FILTERED]", "first_name"=>""}}}
Gateway Error ... An error occurred during processing.  Please try again.
Rendering template within layouts/spree_application
Rendering checkouts/edit
Completed in 4804ms (View: 76, DB: 38) | 200 OK [https://truejey.com/orders/R10712666/checkout]
```

Ok.. a very general Error. But its coming from Authorize.net which tells me it can be either of these :

```
The system-generated void for the original timed-out transaction failed. (The original transaction timed out while waiting for a response from the authorizer.)

The system-generated void for the original errored transaction failed. (The original transaction experienced a database error.)

The system-generated void for the original errored transaction failed. (The original transaction experienced a processing error.)
```

The difference is in what `response_code` I got back whether its `120`, `121`, or `122`.

My question is, how can I find out what was the response_code for this transaction?

Or even better yet, does anyone else have a master way of debugging CC issues like this?